# Spring Boot v1.5.3.RELEASE with Jersey 2 return 404 to all requests JSON

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jersey

I have and application with Spring Boot and Jersey. Here the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cat.amb.parkride</groupId>
    <artifactId>parkride</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>parkride</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mandatory dependencies for using Spock -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mandatory dependencies for using Spock -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Mandatory dependencies for using Spock -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Mandatory dependencies for using Spock -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the main class:

```
package cat.amb.parkride;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import cat.amb.parkride.adapter.rest.BasicRest;
import cat.amb.parkride.config.JerseyConfig;

@SpringBootApplication
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"cat.amb.parkride", "cat.amb.parkride.adapter.rest"})
public class ParkRideApplication {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParkRideApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ParkRideApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my configuration for Jersey:

```
package cat.amb.parkride.config;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import cat.amb.parkride.adapter.rest.AuthRest;
import cat.amb.parkride.adapter.rest.TestRest;
import cat.amb.parkride.adapter.rest.UserRest;

@Configuration
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/parkride/rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        registerEndPoints();
        register(LoggingFilter.class);
    }

    private void registerEndPoints() {
        register(TestRest.class);
        register(AuthRest.class);
        register(UserRest.class);       
    }
}
```

And this is the Rest class:

```
package cat.amb.parkride.adapter.rest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8" })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8" })
public class TestRest extends BasicRest {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestRest.class);

    @Path("/test/v1/test")
    @GET
    public Response test() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Estamos dentro!!");
        return getResponse("OK", null, HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

    @Path("/parkride/rest/test/v1/test")
    @GET
    public Response test2() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Estamos dentro!!");
        return getResponse("OK", null, HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

The structure of packages are:

cat.amb.parkride
            adapter
                dao
            rest
               TestRest.java
            commons
            config
            domain
            ParkRideApplication.java

In every call to this methods i can see in log:

```
2017-05-08 18:37:42.110  INFO 8412 --- [  restartedMain] cat.amb.parkride.ParkRideApplication     : Started ParkRideApplication in 2.219 seconds (JVM running for 70.125)
2017-05-08 18:37:45.275  INFO 8412 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter  : 1 * Server has received a request on thread http-nio-8080-exec-1
1 > GET http://localhost:8080/parkride/rest/test/v1/test
1 > accept: */*
1 > accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
1 > accept-language: es,en;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6
1 > cache-control: no-cache
1 > connection: keep-alive
1 > content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 > host: localhost:8080
1 > postman-token: 34696faf-d1e2-fc6b-28d7-b2db672f2578
1 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3091.0 Safari/537.36

2017-05-08 18:37:45.275  INFO 8412 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter  : 1 * Server responded with a response on thread http-nio-8080-exec-1
1 < 404

2017-05-08 18:37:45.276  INFO 8412 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-05-08 18:37:45.276  INFO 8412 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-05-08 18:37:45.285  INFO 8412 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 9 ms
```

But I can enter in to the REST method, seems like the Jersey takes the request but don't execute the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jersey resource classes needed to annotated with `@Path`. That's the only way they are known to be root resources, even if you register them. They still ned this annotation. Your `TestRest` does not have this. If it's on the `BaseRest` class, that won't work. It needs to be on the concrete implementation that is registered.

In regards to how the final routes will be constructed is based on a combination of the `@ApplicationPath`, the `@Path` on the resource *class* and the `@Path` on the resource *method*. If the resource method has no `@Path`, then the route will be that of the resource class' path. For example

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {}

@Path("/animals")
public class AnimalsResource {

    @GET
    public List<Animal> getAll() {}

    @Path("/{id}")
    pubic Animal getOne(@PathParam("id") int id) {}
}
```

- `GET /api/animals` goes to `AnimalsResource.getAll`
- `GET /api/animals/1` goes to `AnimalsResource.getOne`